# I got something wrong with the else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Note: I'm not a fluent english speaker, so you may see some grammar mistakes here. I'm kinda new to programming and i know i can fix it by putting another else/elif statement, i just trying to get the short possible lines to avoid spamming elif like yandev.

so the thing is, at the #functions i already put if below the gae variable's input, which says that if the input = y or Y then it runs the line below it, which is `print("good. go to www.minecraft.net")`. Now my problem is, when i try to input other letter than Y, it still runs the same line whilst there's already an else line underneath that i think should exclude other words than Y or y. For example, i already input the word "n" at the output console(?) but the output says "good. go to www.minecraft.net" instead the lines at the else statement. is there any possible solution without adding much more elif/else statement?

[Click this link for the image to understand what am i talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eno1t.png)

Comment: Please share your code instead of an image

Comment: `if gae =="Y" or gae =="y" ` or easier `if gae.lower() == "y"`

Comment: better yet, `if gae in ['Y', 'y'] :` -- this way you're not limited to a single character

Answer (score -1):

The line `if gae == "Y" or "y"` should be `if gae == "Y" or gae == "y"` otherwise it will always be true and the code will always print "good. go to www.minecraft.net".